# Converting X & Y to Lat & Lon

Tags: java, sumo

I'm currently working on a school project where we have to set up a traffic simulation. We decided to use [TraaS](http://traas.sourceforge.net/cms/).

TraaS has a method to retrieve the current X and Y coordinates of a given vehicle (see [getPosition](http://traas.sourceforge.net/javadoc/de/tudresden/sumo/cmd/Vehicle.html#getPosition(java.lang.String))). However these X and Y coordinates are not the actual map coordinates, but they are relative to the SUMO net.

The question is: **How to convert these relative coordinates to geo coordinates?**

TraaS has a method named [convertGeo](http://traas.sourceforge.net/javadoc/de/tudresden/sumo/cmd/Simulation.html#convertGeo(double,%20double,%20java.lang.String)) to convert X and Y coordinates to geo coordinates, however the method throws an exception. As far as I can tell I'm passing the correct arguments to the method; two doubles and a string which indicates whether you are converting *to* or *from* geo coordinates. The method throws the following exception:

**SUMO error for command 171: Source position type not supported**

```
//Get a random vehicle from the list of current vehicles in the simulation.
String vehicle = getRandomVehicle(); //Retrieves a random ID of an existing vehicle in the simulatio, don't worry about it,

SumoPosition2D pos = (SumoPosition2D) conn.do_job_get(Vehicle.getPosition(vehicle)); //Retrieves the last X and Y coordinates of the vehicle (example -> X: 6997.111901690444, Y: 7564.062169389001)

Object obj = conn.do_job_get(Simulation.convertGeo(pos.x, pos.y, "False")); //Throws an exception -> SUMO error for command 171: Source position type not supported)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion, Michael.

I have contacted the creator of TraaS and he did confirm it was a bug. The issue has been fixed in r48 (https://sourceforge.net/p/traas/code/48/). The parameters of convertGeo have also changed from (double, double, String) to (double, double, boolean).

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/traas/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/TraaS/) I would say the command is not yet implemented in TraaS. You could either use [TraCI4J](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/) or the python client (recommended because it is the most up to date one) which is already bundled with sumo together with jython (if you need to stick with java).